# Is this sentence acceptable?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence

This is one out of the many holiday pictures I made my sister click.

Is this sentence correct?

Can this be said in any other way?

Comment: This sentence is unintelligible. Try to explain what you meant in a bigger sentence with more words.

Comment: As it stands, it's a sentence fragment and it's unclear what you're trying to say. The sentence would make sense if you added *it is* or *this is* to the start. Or *is out focus* to the end. There are many ways of modifying it that would make it complete.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have edited it. Are there any other ways of modifying it?

Comment: @UhtredRagnarsson I am pointing out at a certain picture in a photo album whilst saying this sentence.

Comment: With *that* sentence, it could be shortened to just *This a picture I made my sister click.* But do you have a particular point of concern?

Comment: what do you mean by the verb "click" if you meant it as a verb at all ?

Comment: @UhtredRagnarsson Presumably what most other people mean by it: using a mouse or similar device to activate a hyperlink on a website or in an app. In this case, clicking a thumbnail of an image in a photo album or photo stream in order to see the full-size version. (Unless Astralbee’s interpretation is correct, which the green tick might indicate – in that case it’s an erroneous use meant to mean ‘take [a picture]’.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentence:

> This is one out of the many holiday pictures I made my sister click.

*Is this sentence correct?* - Grammatically, yes.

*Can this be said in any other way?* - Of course!

My main issue with it is that I don't believe "click" is an idiomatic expression for taking a photograph. "Snap", or "take" would make more sense.

You could say:

> This is one of the many holiday pictures I made my sister take.

You should consider what you are trying to convey - what detail is most important. Are you trying to emphasise the volume of photos you took? You could say:

> This is *just* one of the *countless* holiday pictures I made my sister take.

Are you trying to imply by "*made* my sister take" that you were very *demanding* whilst on holiday? If so, you could say:

> This is just one of the many holiday pictures I made my long-suffering sister take.

There is no need to use more words than you need. If you don't mean to emphasise any of this then you could simply say:

> This is one of my holiday photographs.

It is clear by saying "one of.." that you have more. Also, if you are *in* the photos then it is obvious someone else took it.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful.